# Empty catalina.out log file - "operation not permitted"

Tags: tomcat, catalina, lucee

I'm trying to empty the catalina.out log file by using command "echo > catalina.out", but I keep getting response "-bash: catalina.out: Operation not permitted".

Any help?

Comment: Either the user you are running the command as doesn't have permission to the write the catalina.out file or tomcat is running and holding the file open.

Comment: yup, tomcat was running (even though viewing the webpage gave me a 'page cannot be displayed', so i thought it wasn't running. must have still be running in the background. rebooted machine and checked again...was able to kill it. thanks!

Comment: For next time, if someone provides the solution in the comments, asking them to promote *their* comment to an answer is a nice gesture. It givens them an opportunity to earn a few votes as a way of saying thanks for helping out :-)

Answer (score 0):

yup, tomcat was running (even though viewing the webpage gave me a 'page cannot be displayed', so i thought it wasn't running. must have still be running in the background. rebooted machine and checked again...was able to kill it. thanks!